# how to upload multiple dataframes in one gs_edit_cells command

Tags: r, r-googlesheets

I am sure others using the `googlesheets` package would encounter this question some time or the other.
Since googlesheets `gs_edit_cells()` is known to be very slow, is there a way to upload multiple data frames on to multiple anchor points in the same file in a single invocation of the command?

So if I have 2 data frames: df1 and df2  instead of invoking

```
gs_edit_cells(ss=.., ws=.., input=df1, anchor="A1")
gs_edit_cells(ss=.., ws=.., input=df2, anchor="G1")`
```

do we have a way to invoke it something like:

```
gs_edit_cells(ss=.., ws=.., input=c(df1,df2), anchor=c("A1","G1")
```

Since these are small dataframes with independent summary reports, we cannot combine them into one dataframe.

Comment: Likely not. You need to run command in a loop as from [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/googlesheets/versions/0.2.1/topics/gs_edit_cells) *input* takes a single object. And API interfacing like this package cannot be vectorized since you interact with other objects and instances (spreadsheet, worksheets, etc.).

Comment: Got it. So the best bet at the moment is combining the dataframes together and uploading in one shot assuming that we can order the dataframes to show separate reports with new lines and add blank columns etc.